# Primary Key Always Inserting Zero

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, primary-key

I just started learning Entity Framework and I am trying to insert data into data base. I have Customer table which has three fields id(int), name(varchar) and address(varchar). When I am trying to insert data into database every time ID is inserted as 0 value.

My Customer Class-

```
[Table("customer")]
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [Column("custId")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int custId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

And My Insert Methods-

```
static void insertCustomer(Customer cust)
    {
        using(var context = new DBEntities())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: " + cust.custId);
            context.customer.Add(cust);
            context.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("Customer Inserted Successfully!!!");
        }
    }
```

And I am calling Insert method like this

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
cust.custId = 106;
cust.name = "Prince";
cust.address = "Kolkata";
insertCustomer(cust);
```

I am using MySql Database, please someone help, thanks

Comment: show us how you are assigning data to the customer class.

Comment: Are you providing `cust` with an ID anywhere? Are you assigning anything to it? From your code you're creating the field but not actually providing it with a value, hence the `0` assignment..

Comment: I know in SQL server you can assign autoincrement on a column. Every time an item is inserted with id 0 a new id is given automatically. Did you do that on the MySQL database?

Comment: Do you know that the ID in the database is zero - if the MySQL table is set up to auto-increment the ID, then you need to read the record back after it is saved. You are displaying the value before it is saved.

Comment: @JayGould, Yes I assigning cusId. And I am also try to print that ID. Which is printing same whatever I assigned.

Comment: @rish can you show us the code where you're assigning the ID?

Comment: @JayGould thanx for reponse, I have edited my question, please check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably assuming that by adding

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

... on a property, that it tells EF to automatically populate the value. But that's not the case.

It's actually the other way around.  By decorating a property with that attribute, you are telling EF that it doesn't need to validate or worry about that value, and that the database will take care of populating it with an auto-incrementing value.

However, this relies on you having defined the database table correctly to produce that behavior.  It doesn't happen automatically.  You need to make sure that your MySQL table has the column defined correctly as [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's being entered as `0` because you never give it a value different than it's `implicitly initialised` value of 0.

For example, take this method:

```
public void NewCustomer(string _name, int _id) 
{
    Customer cust = new Customer();
    cust.name = _name;
    cust.id = _id;
    InsertCustomer(cust);
}
```

Here you are *assigning* `cust` with the ID being passed to NewCustomer(). This could be an increment used from your DB, a local variable or whatever.

From your code, it's not obvious if you're actually giving `id` a value, you're simply printing an uninitialised variable with has been given the default of`0`.

*edit: if you were looking to use a MySQL `autoincrement`, this is done within your database. You can then assign a cast a record from your database to a `Customer` object and assign an `id` using your `{get; set;}`*